# How do I get my UI changes of my angular Spring to display

Tags: java, spring, angular, eclipse, maven

I'm working on a REST application in eclipse using Spring MVC and angular 5 that was built using maven and running on a Tomcat server.  I have to deploy it by doing a maven build which places a war file in a target directory then dragging the war file to the wtpwebapps deployment path.  My main issues is that once I make changes to the UI (I'm using VS code for the angular changes) and refresh the project and rebuild the war, The changes I make still don't appear when I run the application.  I'm sure there's an easier way to deploy it in the first place but I'm puzzled as to why the fresh new war file doesn't have the most current changes?

*UPDATE* I ended up switching to a pivotal tc server which extends tomcat functionality.  I can see my changes now.  Still have to redeploy the war whenever I save but at least now I can see the changes.  I'll investigate trying to hot deploy

Comment: Does the WAR actually contain the changes?  If yes, is Tomcat configured to re-load without a restart?  If no, backtrack through the various tools to find the failure point.

Comment: So i have an overlying project then I have to subprojects for the spring application and the UI side.  The war builds to the spring apps target directory but it doesn't actually contain the ui portion which is interesting because I can still run the application on server. I just tried to add the UI portion via deployment assembly in project properties but still no update